# Wordpress on Docker: how to update website/plugin?

Tags: docker

I have my wordpress running on LAMP, and now I would like to move it in Docker. I was wondering: how to handle wordpress and plugins updates?

I see two "easy" paths:

- Deploy a basic version of the website, and If I need to redeploy it for whatever reason I'll need to reupdate everything (probably a mess because of the database) - so not really viable.
- Keep the website's data persistent (I'm not using the wp docker image anyway), and mount a volume in the container with the wp files. In this way, the update would be persisted.

What I really want is to store on git and then build a new image every time there is a wordpress update.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: _"have an history of my website's version"_ … That's what Version Control System like Git were meant to be. But if you are managing data like your DB or a static website, your NFS mount for your document or image library, then yes, this is a good idea.

Comment: Regarding my statement, If I had a way to build the image for each plugin/blabla update, then it (probably) implies that I'm also storing my code somewhere (Git for sure :)).

Comment: Btw, that would be just an additional benefit, I would rather not store the code of the website on the persistent storage, and just mount the uploads folder (this is the main point of my question). But thanks for the clariifcation though!

Comment: I don't know of anybody who rebuilds their container image on every single update of a theme, it's time consuming and expensive, that's what git/svn/etc is for, even the big enterprise grade WP hosts do it that way. Keep in mind this is stack exchange, it's a Q&A site not a discussion forum, you need to have a specific question that can be canonically answered, as in you need to mark and accept an answer that's not just the best answer, and not just the most helpful answer, but **the** answer to this question for all people

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point about your comment, TBH. My question should be clear: I have my wp (the code) instance in a docker container. Since I want to build a new container instance when I update the code (or call it for each new "release" of my code), and this update should happen outside the container. I want to know if this is possible given the fact that my code is wordpress, and an update might be a wordpress's core update.